# Getting error trying to use array index in my lists

Tags: c#

I m posting few code here for you to see, the error is on names[]

```
var names = new Lists<string>();
while(true)
 {

            Console.Write("type a name (or hit ENTER to quit)");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            break;
          names.Add(input);
  }

  if (names.count >2)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} and {2} others like your posts", names[0], names[1], names.count - 2);}
}
}
```

I am having an error on names[0], names[1], saying cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of `list<string>`.

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: `names` is not a `List<T>`, it's a `Lists<T>` - which is not a built-in .NET Framework type.

Comment: just change first line.That is List<String> NOT Lists<string>

Comment: Working example. Online compilers are very good this days. Check it out: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oF7XnL AND it has basic code analyzer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few small tweaks needed. Primarily, you are using `Lists` but this should be `List`.

`var names = new List<string>();`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var names = new List<string>();
            while(true)
            {

                Console.Write("type a name (or hit ENTER to quit)");
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
                break;
            names.Add(input);
    }

    if (names.Count >2)
       Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} and {2} others like your posts", names[0], names[1], names.Count - 2);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Murray, I'm new to c# I finally fixed the error and it also my first time to use the stack overflow

Comment: Sure, no problem. I could see you had made a good effort so happy to help. Please accept the answer on stack overflow. Good luck!

Comment: If you still around please check my second part of codes

Comment: I dont see your second part on the question - you should post it up as a new question.